# Increment the elements of an array by 1 (1 thru 1000)

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sh

I ma still a ROOKIE when it comes to shell script. Long story short I am trying the increment the values of the array by one for every iteration. Here is my code

```
cmd=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ................)  // How can I pass numbers 1 to 1000 with out having to type manually.
${cmd[@]}

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#cmd[@]} ; i++ )) do
echo ${cmd[$i]}"

done
```

One approach would be cmd=() and then inside the loop we add the line "let cmd[i]++" , but it didnt work for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just trying to initialize the `cmd` array to the numbers 1...1000?  Or do you want to initialize the array, and then also increment elements of the array?

Comment: @robmayoff Either way is fine. As long as the value that gets excuted by the command is incremented by 1 for every iteration.   I am trying what I have been advised to do .(below suggestions).But if we can do it  some other way, please share .it is good to know as well

Comment: In bash {1..1000} is evaluated as 1 2 3 4 5 6 up to 1000. Newer bash version even supports increment like {1..11..2} will evaluate to 1 3 5 7 9 11.

Comment: You can simply do: `for (( i=1 ; i <= 10000; i++ )) do echo $i; done`

Comment: @anubhava  I needed it inside an array.

Comment: Even then `cmd=({1..1000})` is better way of achieving that since it doesn't call any external BASH utility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) command

```
cmd=( $(seq 1 1000) )
```

Comment: I will replace cmd=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ................) with cmd=( $(seq 1000) ) and see what happens thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 7):

If you are running bash you may take advantage of its features.

Try:

```
cmd=({1..1000})
```

Comment: There is an advantage to this over $(seq 1000). $(seq 1000) will spawn a subshell while {1...1000} is native to bash and doesn't spawn a subshell.

Comment: Ran a little test: using brace expansion is about 20% faster than using `seq` (a single invocation is so fast, however - around .005 secs. on a modern desktop - that it probably won't matter). Finally, a quibble - `seq`, as an external executable, runs in a *child process*, not a subshell.

Comment: @user3088572 FYI, I also wanted to skip some numbers inside the array and was able to achieve this by doing                                   cmd=( {2..100} {300..553} {550..100} )

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

```
cmd=( $(seq 1000) )
```

in order to create the array.

Comment: +1 - didn't know that specifying the start number is optional and defaults to 1.